# Which runner to use with Specflow Cucumber BDD: Specflow Runner, Nunit, Xunit

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, bdd, specflow

I have a Specflow Selenium BDD automation solution in C# using Visual Studio and want to start scheduling some automation runs based on tags and possibly features.

I've only used Nunit as a test runner in the past. Does Specflows own runner offer any distinct advantages? I'm also considering Xunit.

I was hoping to find a comparison somewhere but had no luck, is this just a personal choice thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Configuring the Unit Test Provider Tests are executed using a unit
> test provider. Add the corresponding NuGet package to your project to
> define your unit test provider:
>
> SpecRun.Runner SpecFlow.xUnit SpecFlow.MsTest SpecFlow.NUnit You can
> only have one unit test provider!
>
> <sub>Source: [Executing SpecFlow Scenarios](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Execution/Executing-SpecFlow-Scenarios.html)</sub>

All these frameworks are supported , why would you want to switch to xunit?

```
 nunit3-console.exe mytest.dll --where="Description=='Login' and cat == ie"
```

This is an example to run feature having name Login and tag having name or ie

Comment: thanks, yes thats how I've used Nunit in the past. I was curious as to whether switching unit test provider to Specflows own SpecRun.Runner (or Xunit) would give any additional functions or benefits.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58374136/6793637. This is the answer from specflow maintainer itself

Answer (score 1):

xUnit.

( ... or even unittest, pytest, if you would consider python:
"unittest : A unit testing framework for Python. It is python’s xUnit style framework." )